# Modify function of DataWindow does not work properly in PB10.5

Tags: powerbuilder, datawindow

So I have a string with a large sql query named `sql_select`. And I have the following code in PowerBuilder 10.5:

```
dw_1.Modify( "DataWindow.Table.Select=' "+ sql_select + "'" )
messagebox("Something", dw_1.getsqlselect())
```

I see that I do not get the full query, i.e., some conditions do not exist! Even though the `sql_select` is right. What is the problem?

Comment: It is difficult to get the answer with my crystal ball without any information concerning the dw structure and without any information about the content of the `sql_select`. Is the query correctly escaped for the DW syntax?

Comment: Yeap it seems that was somehow related. Thank you!

Comment: For future reference...The problem was related with some escaped quotes in the query. Also I wasn't getting the result of modify as @Seki suggested.

Now it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get the result of the `dw_1.modify()` call into a string variable. If there is any problem from the syntax, you should get an error message in the string. If there is no problem for `Modify()` the string will remain empty.

Answer (score 0):

You may also be passed through the method of the object setsqlselect datawinow. 
But the return value is not readily exploitable being -1 on error occur...., and 1 if it passes.

Did you have the same number of column in your query and you dataobject?

Did you try to execute the query stocked in sql_select with your DBMS?